# Pygame não executa um arquivo.mp3 e retorna pygame-error

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pygame

### Estava mexendo no `Pygame` e ao executar um programa que toca musicas:

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('ex021.mp3') # Dark Souls III Soundtrack OST - Main Theme.mp3
mixer.music.play()
input()
```

Ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Exception has occurred: pygame.error
Couldn't open 'ex021.mp3'
  File "/home/alanmaxwell/Documentos/Projects/VS Code/curso-python3/Mundo 01: Fundamentos/ex021.py", line 8, in <module>
    mixer.music.load('ex021.mp3') # Música - Dark Souls III Soundtrack OST - Main Theme.mp3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

SOMENTE no VS Code, em outras IDE's como Pycharm por exemplo, ele executa normalmente. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

---

OBS: Instalei o Pygame normalmente no ambiente virtual e o arquivo.mp3 está na mesma pasta do arquivo.py, já tentei usar o `mixer.load()` tanto com o nome do arquivo, quanto informando o caminho.

Comment: A sua foto do erro faltou a linha mais importante, a última! Por favor [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/364020/edit) a pergunta e adicione o restante do erro. Além disso, coloque em formato texto, e não em imagem.

Comment: @nosklo Pronto, o erro está em modo texto, mas as linhas de erro eram somente as da foto mesmo, nenhuma a mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É provável que a IDE que você está usando não use como diretório atual o diretório onde está o script, sendo assim, ao tentar abrir o arquivo sem especificar o caminho, como você está fazendo, ele não será encontrado.

Tente rodar o seguinte script, para testar se este é o caso:

```
import os; print(os.getcwd()) # mostra o diretorio atual
```

Se não mostrar o mesmo caminho onde está o script, então, está confirmado que este é o seu problema.

Para consertar existem algumas formas:

1. colocar o caminho completo do arquivo `.mp3` no seu código, para que o mesmo possa ser executado independente de qual é o diretório atual.
2. Detectar o caminho do script e usá-lo (usando , por exemplo, `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'ex021.mp3')`

Comment: Deu certo colocando o caminho completo do arquivo e também mantendo o nome original do mesmo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui aqui colocando o endereço completo do arquivo. por exemplo ficou assim meu código:

```py
import pygame

# Inicializando o mixer PyGame
pygame.mixer.init()

# Iniciando o Pygame
pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load('c:/workspace/iniciando-com-python/exercicios/SportRockByScottHolmesMusic.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0, start=0.0)
pygame.event.wait()
input('Ta rolando o rockzin?')
```

Answer (score -2):

eu consegui, mas só depois que eu atualizei meu pip pelo prompt do windows (admito que não sei se faz diferença), segue meu código:

pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.init()

(5, 0)

pygame.mixer.music.load('C:/Users/Raquel/05 Carry You Home.mp3')

pygame.mixer.music.play()

#eu coloquei esse próximo código depois de ouvir um cadinho da música

pygame.mixer.music.stop()

pra pegar o caminho da música (lembrando que eu estou no windows 10, 32 bits),eu fui no Explorador de Arquivos, encontrei a música, cliquei com o botão esquerdo (talvez no seu seja o outro botão) do mouse, cliquei em copiar e colei em pygame.mixer.load('aqui dentro,entre aspas').

Answer (score -3):

voce escreveu algumas linhas meio que atoas, tente só fazer assim

import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('SportRockByScottHolmesMusic.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
input(' ')

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).